# Nginx Sub domain setup

Tags: nginx, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to setup Nginx so I can have sub domains like

```
www.MySite.com - Main website (Works correctly)
jenkins.MySite.com - sub domain for Jenkins
gitlab.MySite.com - sub domain for Gitlab
```

I've tried following various tutorials and I seem to have included everything required to make this work, but still to no avail.

I've followed this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins
and various other sources online.

[Nginx Server Block]
 I've edited my nginx.conf file, I've created a new nginx/sites-available conf file for Jenkins and symlinked it to sites-enabled.

This is my default jenkins JENKINS_ARGS

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT -ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
```

This is an example of my jenkins server block in nginx

```
server 
{
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server 
{

listen 443;
server_name jenkins.MySite.com;

#ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

#ssl on;
#ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
#ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins/access.log;

location / 
{

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.MySite.com;
}
}
```

I've also created an A record in DigitalOcean - Network
and also a CNAME

Much help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: All these 3-setups need separate ngnix config files and supervirosor files as you did for main site. make soft link of those files and put them in respective etc/nginx/sites-avai and sites-enable and also soft link the supervisor files to etc/supervisor/conf.d

Comment: @Shivkumar Kondi  Sorry, I didn't explain that part. I have 2 config files so far, one for the site and one for Jenkins. The site works fine, but it's Jenkins that isn't running the command, works fine too and is successful.

Answer (score 0):

All these 3-setups need separate ngnix config files and supervirosor files as you did for main site. make soft link of those files and put them in respective etc/nginx/sites-avai and sites-enable and also soft link the supervisor files to etc/supervisor/conf.d

To check whether the nginx file is properly configured, you need to test it.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that part. I have 2 config files so far, one for the site and one for Jenkins. The site works fine, but it's Jenkins that isn't

running the command, works fine too and is successful.